# Protobuf 2.4.x && 2.5.x compatibility

Tags: protocol-buffers

I find it very convenient to persist data using binary protobuf messages. Now I want to migrate from 2.4.x protobuf to 2.5.x and I am worried about backwards compatibility.

Will new protobuf library be able to read 2.4.x protobuf binary message?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Should be just a drop-in upgrade. They are fully compatible on the wire and backward compatible in terms of the definition language and language APIs.

By the way, you should probably upgrade to 2.6.1 which is the latest stable release in 2.x.x series.

Answer (score 3):

> Will new protobuf library be able to read 2.4.x protobuf binary message?

The latest version of protobufs can still read messages from ~14 years ago. :) Google has massive amounts of data in this format, so you can be sure that they will never, ever break compatibility.

Comment: That's pleasant to hear!

Comment: will it work the other way ? write a message in protobuf version 2.6 and read it from 2.4 ?

Comment: @Knight71 Yes, absolutely.